# buliding wix from source code

Tags: wix

I am building wix from source code. On executing make.bat (present in root folder of WIX source) file, first i got NAnt not found. So I downloaded NAnt and updated make.bat file. On executing the file again I am getting this error.

```
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\V
SIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\V
SIP\10.0\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
 [property] Target framework changed to "Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0".
 [property] Read-only property "dir.hhw" cannot be overwritten.
 [property] Read-only property "hhw-found" cannot be overwritten.
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1
0.0\Setup\VS\Pro\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1
0.0\Setup\VS\VSTA\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1
0.0\Setup\VS\VSTD\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\1
0.0\Setup\VS\VSTT\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
     [echo] Pre-requisite Check Passed: Visual Studio 10.0 Test Tools are instal
led.
     [echo] Pre-requisite Check Passed: .Net Framework 4.0 Full is installed.
     [echo] Pre-requisite Check Passed: Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll is inst
alled.
     [echo] Pre-requisite Check Failed: Qtests directory was not found.

global.initTools:

     [echo] Found Visual Studio 2005 VC Directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro
soft Visual Studio 8\VC\
     [echo] Found Visual Studio 2010 VC Directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro
soft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\
     [echo] Found Visual Studio 2008 VC Directory : C:\Program Files (x86)\Micro
soft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\
     [echo] Setting main VC directory to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visu
al Studio 9.0\VC\
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs
\Windows\v7.1\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
[readregistry] Registry Path Not Found! - key='SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Mi
crosoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\';hive='Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive[]';
     [echo] Setting PlatformSDKDir directory to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\

BUILD FAILED - 8 non-fatal error(s), 2 warning(s)
```

Comment: I have visual studio 2010 premium edtion installed on my machine so dont think would need .Net framework 3.5 also I have Mi crosoft windows server 2008 enterprise r2 edition

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need Visual Studio SDK: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2680